# mvc3 partialview target by div tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, ajaxform

I have an issue with a `partialview`, for some reason when I do a **Post** on it; it gives me another copy of my form; how can I make that behavior go away . This is what that `partialview` looks like:

```
// this is all inside my partialview
<div style=" float:left;">
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("posting", "post", null, new AjaxOptions
 {
     UpdateTargetId = "glober",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     HttpMethod = "POST"
 }))
 {
   // taken out
}
</div>
<div id="glober">

@foreach (var item in Model.Mymodel)
{
}

</div>
```

as you can see this is a POST and I only want to update the part with the `id` of "glober" which it does but for some reason when I do the post it also gives me a second copy of the form elements. If inside my ajax form I have 1 `textbox` called firstname then after submitting it I get 2 `textboxes` that says firstname, any help would be great.
Part of my controller is this were i call out the partial

```
 var iefeeds = sqlConnection.Query<thread>("Select * from postings").ToList();
                    return PartialView("_mypartial");
```

Comment: put you controller too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have returned `View` rather than `PartialView` in the controller. So you'll see 2 pages overlapping in response of **ajax Post**.